# Generating a uniform distribution of 64-bit integers

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, statistics

I'm using

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var uid = crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(8);
```

to generated 64-bit IDs.

I don't need these to be truly random, but I would like them to be uniformly distributed between `0` and `ffffffffffffffff`. However, they are not. Generating 1,000,000 64-bit integers this way:

```
var bignum = require('bignum');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var randomBignum = function() { 
    return bignum.fromBuffer(crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(8));
}

var avg = randomBignum();
var avg_len = avg.bitLength();
var lengths = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    var big = randomBignum();
    avg = avg.add(big).div(2);
    var length = big.bitLength();
    if (typeof lengths[length] === 'undefined') { lengths[length] = 0; }
    lengths[length] += 1;
    avg_len = (avg_len + length) / 2;
}
console.log('Average integer: %s', avg);
console.log('Average bit length: %s', avg_len);
console.info('Bit length distribution: %s', require('util').inspect(lengths));
```

produces:

```
Average integer: 8386866841744540769
Average bit length: 63.11672078688376
Bit length distribution: {
  '45': 1,
  '47': 2,
  '48': 7,
  '49': 15,
  '50': 23,
  '51': 66,
  '52': 114,
  '53': 248,
  '54': 521,
  '55': 955,
  '56': 1905,
  '57': 4019,
  '58': 7742,
  '59': 15552,
  '60': 31396,
  '61': 63048,
  '62': 125182,
  '63': 249271,
  '64': 499933 }
```

I may be confused about the stats here, but these are not uniformly distributed, right? The fact that each byte is individually randomly generated makes it improbable that successive 0-bytes will be generated, so you get exponentially fewer small numbers.

What is a good and fast way to generate uniformly distributed, 64-bit IDs in Node? Should I use `Math.random` and multiply the result by `ffffffffffffffff`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They (probably) *are* uniform! The probability of getting 0 is the same as the probability of getting 18446744073709551615, but there are 4611686018427387904 numbers in that range with no leading zeroes, and only one with 64 of them. You should expect to see each bit count appearing approximately twice as much as the previous one, which your test agrees with.

Comment: Haha I /just/ updated my question to elaborate that. Ok, great—I was not sure! Thank you.

Comment: Even the simplest things about stats can sometimes really bend my mind.

Comment: And if I may follow up, then: why would you call this "uniform"? Due to the psuedo-random generation, wouldn't you call this a non-uniform distribution? I'm trying to generate UIDs with the least likelihood of collision.

Comment: Well, I'm going for the broadest use of the address space, to avoid collisions. It doesn't have to be perfect, but I can't tell if this approach facilitates that.

Comment: @dimadima: “Uniform” refers to a distribution of probability, i.e. that every option is equally likely. So yes, the numbers you get are uniformly distributed, assuming the random number generator is fair.

Comment: Gotcha! So that makes sense... I make the most of the address space (meaning, filling it up and avoiding collisions) by generating a distribution of addresses with equal likelihood (or, uniform probability distribution) of generation. Just because the resulting values are not uniformly distributed `0-n` does not mean that the probability distribution is not uniform.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for correcting 2^63 to 2^64, was confused about that.

Comment: @dimadima: Yep! Since you want to avoid collisions, you could use every integer (in a row or otherwise), but that usually takes some effort and isn’t even always possible.

Comment: Great, thanks again. Yeah, I'm taking this approach as the simplest possible method to generate short-ish UIDs for a distributed system, where incrementing integers is not possible.